# php file renaming while running - is a lock possible?

Tags: php, file-io

I am going to need to make changes to a `php` file in runtime.
This is a configuration file that upon emergency would need a change to one of its settings.
My question is whether it is possible to `lock` the file before writing so that other sessions that try to access that file would postpone until the file is rewritten, and not crash the session saying the file was not found ?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, please see the manual entry for [flock](http://php.net/manual/en/function.flock.php) function

Example from the manual:

```
<?php

$fp = fopen("/tmp/lock.txt", "r+");

if (flock($fp, LOCK_EX)) {  // acquire an exclusive lock
    ftruncate($fp, 0);      // truncate file
    fwrite($fp, "Write something here\n");
    fflush($fp);            // flush output before releasing the lock
    flock($fp, LOCK_UN);    // release the lock
} else {
    echo "Couldn't get the lock!";
}

fclose($fp);

?>
```

Apparently there are some caveats, for instance if you're using an antiquated filesystem (FAT) `flock()` will always return false.  If you're using PHP as an ISAPI extension, then `flock` will not lock the file from being modified/read by other PHP Scripts running in parallel threads.